# Easy Stats analysis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Would be grateful if anyone can help. I have answers to a questionnaire and I want to compare between group A and B, possible say there is no difference in their response between these two groups. What (easy!) stats method would be best to use?

[image]

Comment: a $2\times k$ chisquare test of homogeneity is simplest (or perhaps something like a Fisher exact test given the low expected counts in some categories), but this ignores the ordering in the categories, which may be informative.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a simple chi-square test to see the difference between the two groups.

The following are SAS code to perform chi-square test on your data.

```
data a;
input group$ opionion$ count;
datalines;
1 SD 23 
1 D  37
1 DK 10
1 A  4
1 SA 0
2 D  6
2 D  13
2 DK 3
2 A 2
2 SA 0
;
run;

proc freq data=a;
table group*opionion/exact;
weight count;
run;
```

Results:

[image]

It shows the two group's opinions are different.

Comment: Sorry, just find there is a data entry mistake,  The 6 in group 2 should be SD, After corret that there are not different between two group.